# Assign child element to variable for click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress generated menu that has this structure:

```
<li id="menu-item-407" class="smoothAboutScroll menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-407">
   <a href="#collapseAbout" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseAbout" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseAbout">About Us</a>
</li>
```

I want to target the `<a>` child and store it in a variable, so then I can create a onclick function that runs when the `<a>` element is clicked on.

This is what I have:

```
var aboutLink = $('#menu-item-407').children();
$('aboutLink').on('click', function() {
    // run function 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('aboutLink')` is looking for a `<aboutLink></aboutLink>` element that doesn't exist.

That selector string has nothing to do with the variable `aboutLink` which is now a jQuery object itself

Try

```
var aboutLink = $('#menu-item-407 > a');
aboutLink.on('click', function() {
     // run function 
})
```

Comment: I see what you mean by the string. That was a mistake. Still not working however.

Comment: Any errors in console and is this inside a `jQuery(function(){})` call?

Comment: No errors in the console, and yes it is. I ran a console.log on the aboutLink and got a.fn.init [selector: "#menu-item-407 > a", prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document] so it's there...

Comment: That isn't an indication try `console.log(aboutLink.length)` should not be zero

Comment: Note you could be running into conflicts since that link also has bootstrap properties on it also

Comment: Nope, removed the bootstrap properties and that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<a>` element an `id` and then target it using jquery?

`var myElement = $('#myLinkId');`